# how to make jquery mobile display larger elements?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, scale

I am developing a jQuery Mobile application for a tablet and found that the default element size is somewhat small. I tried to change the meta initial-scale with no luck :(

Is it possible to make jQuery Mobile scale up everything, say by 30%?
Perhaps, a CSS trick would do it?

TIA,
Adrian.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.3, maximum-scale=2">` doesn't work? -- Changing all the CSS might work, but there has to be an easier way :/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a JavaScript way that I have used a fair few times:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="foo">content to be scale to 130%</div>
<div>content that won't be scaled</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var scale = function(target, css_rule, value)
{
    var type = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(target, "").getPropertyValue(css_rule).match(/[a-zA-Z]{0,2}$/); //Get unit type from end of string

    value = (parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(target, "").getPropertyValue(css_rule)) * value); //Get current value of css_rule and multiply by entered value

    target.style.cssText += css_rule + ':' + value + type + ';'; //Add css_rule to cssText with value and type
}
```

You can then call this code with:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];
scale(elem, 'font-size', 1.3);
```

[jsFiddle of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SRXxb/1/)

This example will expand the `font-size` of the class by 30%, you can then apply this to any and all CSS rules you wish to scale up.

You may want to expand my script to delete the old cssText rules that have been overwritten with some `Regular Expressions`, you can read more on this [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

I hope this helps, and there may be an easier way, but this code can be called at any time, allowing you to zoom in and out of elements with ease

**NOTE :**

This example uses an uncommon way of getting the style of an element, `Computed Style`, which only works in Safari, Opera, Google Chrome and Firefox.

For Internet Explorer use: `elem.currentStyle`

Comment: Then, for each element I would have to add class="foo"?

Comment: Yes, you can change the class name to whatever you want, or even change it to class="scale_130" indicating it is 130%, as long as you call the function via that class, after all the elements have that class assigned to it

Comment: Well... There will be lots of class="foo" around... Is it possible to make use of some inheritance mechanism?

Comment: You can and maybe should use the unit 'em' which is percentage based off of whatever it would have been without that CSS rule, so you can try using that everywhere, then only changing the body's values with the scaling, alternatively, you can target possible TagName which sometimes covers more elements than the ClassName